# Intercept in 2nd-stage Error Correction Model (ECM) regression -- yes or no?

Tags: intercept, vector-error-correction-model, ecm

When doing a two-step ECM regression, do we add an intercept in the 2nd stage regression? I've seen course notes that add an intercept in the ECM, but some do not, so I'm confused if I should include it or not.

Comment: What is the first step and what is the second step?

Comment: First stage: predicting the residual from the long-run equation (u-hat). Second-stage: using the lagged value of u-hat as a regressor in the ECM.

Comment: See some discussion in the comments of ["Interpretation of intercept term in ECM"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505811/interpretation-of-intercept-term-in-ecm).